# Python service error: The service process could not connect to the service controller

Tags: python, windows, service, pywin32

I created a Python app that uses FastAPI and fetches data from an SQL Server database in Visual studio code 2022.

And I want to create a windows service from this app.

Here is the code for the MyService.py:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyAPIService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "MyAPIService"

def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
    self.is_alive = True

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
    self.is_alive = False

def SvcDoRun(self):
    servicemanager.LogMsg(
        servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
        servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
        (self._svc_name_, ""),
    )
    self.main()

def main(self):
    from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, workers=1, worker_cls=UvicornWorker
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    servicemanager.Initialize()
    servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyService)
    servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
```

And when I run this command:

python MyService.py install

I get this error:

```
File "D:\Python\Projects\myproject\MyService.py", line 46, in <module>
servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
pywintypes.error: (1063, 'StartServiceCtrlDispatcher', 
'The service process could not     connect to the service controller.')
```

Comment: You can't run from the command line. You need to register the service, e.g. `sc create "MyAPIService" binPath= "c:\python.exe D:\Python\Projects\myproject\MyService.py"`